# How to improve my PHP script to insert into in multiple table?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating a html form to insert informations and upload image files name into a two Mysql table at the same time. The php code that i'm using to register user and upload images to images folder works well, but i didnt get the correctly way to insert, at the same time, an ID from another table.

I found some questions about it but i didn't find a correctly way to solve this:

1. [How to insert multiple values into a table in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245310/how-to-insert-multiple-values-into-a-table-in-php)
2. [insert multiple rows via a php array into mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779986/insert-multiple-rows-via-a-php-array-into-mysql)
3. [Inserting multiple rows in a table using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667384/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-table-using-php)
4. [How to insert multiple table rows into database using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39385049/how-to-insert-multiple-table-rows-into-database-using-php)

Below are the two tables that demonstrate what i'm doing:

**users_tbl**

```
userID | username
------------------
01     | john
02     | Marie
03     | Joseph
xx     | xxxxx
------------------
```

And below are the table that call **images_tbl** that receive image name:

**images_tbl**

```
id | imageName
-------------------------
01 | my_pic1.jpg
02 | my_pic2.jpg
03 | my_pic3.jpg
04 | my_pic4.jpg
05 | img-1.jpg
06 | img-2.jpg
-------------------------
```

What i would like to do is insert one column into **images_tbl** that call **userID** (foreing key) of **users_tbl**, just to receive the recently created last userID number at the same time that i register and insert the uploaded image name into **images_tbl** table:

**images_tbl**

```
id | userID  |imageName
-------------------------
01 | 01      |my_pic1.jpg
02 | 01      |my_pic2.jpg
03 | 01      |my_pic3.jpg
04 | 02      |img02.jpg
05 | 02      |img03.jpg
xx | xx      |xxxxxxx.jpg
-------------------------
```

Based on the table above, the php code (**insert.php**) that i'm using to register an user into (**user_tbl**) table and, at the same time, insert images name into **images_tbl** table, is showed below:

```php
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// prepare and bind
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users_tbl (username) VALUES (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);

// set parameters and execute
$firstname = $_POST['username'];
$stmt->execute();

echo "New records created successfully";

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
?>

<?php
if(!empty($_FILES)){

// Include the database configuration file

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

    // File path configuration

    $targetDir = "uploads/";
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $targetFilePath = $targetDir.$fileName;

// Here is the part of this code that i'm not be able to fix this:

$lastUserID = "SELECT userID FROM users_tbl ORDER BY userID DESC LIMIT 1";

    // Upload file to server

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetFilePath)){

        // Insert file information in the database - $fileName and $lastUserID

        $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO images_tbl (imageName, userID) VALUES ('".$fileName."','".$lastUserID."')");
    }
}
?>
```

Finally, the html form code that i'm using to do this:

```html
<form action="insert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

<input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
<br>
<div class="dropzone"></div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="startUpload" value="ADD"> 

</form>
```

As the form above, i'm using Dropzone.js to upload image files and, as i said, the php code that i'm using, upload images files into to **uploads** folder and insert data into **users_tbl** but doesn't insert **userID** into userID column of **images_tbl** table.

How can i adaptate my php code **insert.php** to insert userID correctly into **images_tbl** table? Any tips?

Comment: can you comment the query that you get after dumping  the insert into images_tbl query

Comment: To insert into images_tbl, i created a variable to store userID value and then i put this variable into $insert query to store userID value into images_tbl, but it isn't works:
$lastUserID = "SELECT userID FROM users_tbl ORDER BY userID DESC LIMIT 1";

    // Upload file to server

    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetFilePath)){

        // Insert file information in the database - $fileName and $lastUserID

        $insert = $db->query("INSERT INTO images_tbl (imageName, userID) VALUES ('".$fileName."','".$lastUserID."')");
    }
}

Comment: Excuse me, but on my insert.php file you can see that i'm using mysqli prepared statements. Just take a look before invalid my question. Thks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$lastuserid = mysqli_insert_id($conn);` function to save the id of the user being created to a variable and then use that to update the other table.